# (React JS) How to validate third party input components like ( react-phone-input-2) with other third party forms

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a form in which I am using react-phone-input-2 component for taking mobile number input from the user. But I am also using AvForms (generally any other third party forms), so I don't know how to validate them and show errors the same as the "third party forms" providing.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {};
return (
<AvForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <AvField name="name" label="Name" required />
  <AvField name="email" label="Email" required />
  <PhoneInput
    country={"pk"}
  />
  <FormGroup>
    <Button>Submit</Button>
  </FormGroup>
</AvForm>
```

Comment: Could you post some code we can take a look at?

Comment: Ok I will post it in a while.

Comment: The third party library may or may not handle errors. If they don't, you can validate the state and output any errors below each respective input.

Answer (score 1):

You should hook into the method that is used to set the value when onChange happens and inject it into the component or use the build in method of the compoent.

```
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2'

const MyImput = function(){

    const [phone, setPhone] = useState(null)
    const [isValid, setValid] = useStatr(null)

    const valid = value => {
        // here you validate your phone
    }

    const handleChange = value => {
        setPhone(value)
        valid(value)
            ? setValid(true)
            : setValid(false)
    }


    return <>
        <PhoneInput
            isValid={isValid}
            country={'us'}
            value={phone}
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <PhoneInput
            isValid={(value, country) => {
                if (value.match(/12345/)) {
                    return 'Invalid value: ' + value + ', ' + country.name;
                } else if (value.match(/1234/)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }}/>
    </>

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: Actually it displays error on top of the input filed but I want to show it below the field like other fields in form.

Comment: So what you have to do is remove the isValid prop from the input and create a higher order component as a wrapper for your input and provide additional styles. Do you accept the answer?